# output dimension of reshape layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
```

The dense layer takes input of 1*100 dimension. It uses 7*7*256 nodes in it's layer. Reshape layer takes 1*(7*7*256) as input and what's it's output. I mean what does (7, 7, 256) means ?

Is it the image of dimension 7 * 7 if we give input as image of 1*100? What is it ?

I am sorry, I know that I have understood it in a completely wrong way. So I wanted to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your model will take an input_shape of (*, 100), the first dense layer will output a shape of ( * , 7*7*256) and finaly the last Reshape layer will reshape that output to an array of shape (*, 7, 7, 256).

With * being your batch_size.

So yeah basically, your 'image' of shape (,100) will be reshaped to an array of shape 
(, 7, 7, 256).

Hope this will help you

Comment: Does that mean the image of dimension 7 * 7 * 256 ?

Comment: I got it thank you. But what's the math's behind it? I mean how it changes 1 * 100 to 7 * 7* 256 ?

Answer (score 0):

This has reference to the  google's tensorflow mnist dcgan tutorial.

The first dense layer at the input is configured to have number of filters 7 * 7 * 256 and we are not able to find an explanation for this in the tutorial.

My initial impression about this is as follows:

Remember we want a 28x28 grey scale image as output. That means the required output shape is (None, 28, 28, 1) where first entity is batch size, which is none if a single image is required.

Now note that a Conv2DTranspose layer with strides=(2,2) essentially upsamples the input shape by a factor of 2, it doubles it. Secondly the number of filters of Conv2DTranspose layer become the channels, if I want the output to be grey scale, the number of filters should be one. Thus, if I want (None, 28,28,1) at the output of Conv2DTranspose layer, the shape of its input should be (None, 14,14,x). (No if channels is rather decided by current layer, x can be any value at input).

Suppose I am again putting one more Conv2DTranspose layer with strides=(2,2), before this layer, obviously the input to this layer should be (None, 7,7,x) where x is number of filters.

In general, if a batch of images of size  (h, w) is input to a Conv2DTranspose layer with strides = (2,2), its output will have shape (batch_size, 2 * h, 2 * w , no_of_filters)

The  google tutorial further puts one more Conv2DTranspose layer  [but with strides =(1,1) so it does not have the upsampling effect] and a Dense layer on top of it. These layers are not doing upsampling so the input shape remains 7x7. 7x7 is the image shape here. The first dense layer's output is in flattened shape, so if it has 7 * 7 * x units, we can always reshape it to get an  (7,7,x) image.

This is theory behind that 7 * 7 *x number of units of first dense layer. The value 256 they have used is an arbitrary value which they might have derived empirically or intuitively, I guess.